# MySQL server has gone away - production site

Tags: 7, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving “MySQL server has gone away”, mysql error 2006](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/solving-mysql-server-has-gone-away-mysql-error-2006)

My website is moved from localhost to virtual hosting and after 1 week I receive an error 2006 2006 MySQL server has gone away. Now I can create/edit content but not content types and cannot clear the cache, I see white screen in this case. My hoster said that the max_allowed_packed size is only 1M and I cannot change it.

Is there a way to fix this error?

---

I deleted content types I don't use now and the problem has gone away... And now I can also clear the cache and edit other content types. What it was I cannot understand, it's beyond me

Comment: Thats just a band aid fix. It will hurt when it rips off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Culprit may be [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) which is [too little](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html). [Drupal Requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements/database) page suggests 16M, but it depends on your site. If you are not able to get sufficient memory allocated, better change host.

> When using Drupal 5.x or later, particularly with contributed modules,
>   it may be necessary to set the system variable max_allowed_packet to
>   at least 16M. Some inexpensive hosting plans set this value too low
>   (the MySQL default is only 1M). In that case, you may need to choose a
>   better hosting plan. A value of 1M may be sufficient for 5.x.

Comment: Yes, I have had the same problem a couple of times and I solved it by increasing the `max_allowed_packet` using `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = <NEW_VALUE>`. Changing the value like this will only affect the current session, but you could set it in your mysql config file instead.

Comment: thank you for your advices, guys. May be I will try to move to another hosting though I have another website (D6) but it has not any similar problems on the same hosting

Comment: I have the same problem with max_allowed_packet. in my shared server it is set to 1M. I have contacted to my hosting provider but he doesn't accept to increase it. is there any programming way to solve this issue?