# Error message AJAX "Add a code field"

Tags: 7, ajax

I always get the following error message when I try to add a code field to a content type in the section 'Manage display':

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path:
>   /MYSITE/?q=admin/structure/ds/ajax/add_field/custom_field
>   StatusText: Service unavailable (with message) ResponseText:
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has
>   gone away in variable_set() (line 971 of
>   C:\wamp\www\MYSITE\includes\bootstrap.inc).

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving "MySQL server has gone away", mysql error 2006](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/solving-mysql-server-has-gone-away-mysql-error-2006)

Comment: Page not properly loaded or may be firbug opened.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MySQL server management and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when the `max_allowed_packet` value in your MySQL configuration (my.cnf file) is set to a low value. Increase the value (to, say, `24M`), reboot your MySQL and give it another shot. Depending on your site & server, you may need a higher or lower value.